# How to calculate the yield to maturity?

Tags: actuarial-science

I am looking at an example problem in my textbook and its solution. Can someone look at this picture/ problem and its solution and tell me where they got the yield to maturity.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yield maturity is the constant discount rate that makes the present value of the cash flows equal to the bond price.

Thus

$$114.49 = 100(1+y)^{-4} + 10\sum_{k=1}^{4} (1+y)^{-k}  = 10\frac{(1+y)^{-1}[1-(1+y)^{-4}]}{1 - (1+y)^{-1}}+100(1+y)^{-4}\\=10\frac{1-(1+y)^{-4}}{y}+100(1+y)^{-4}$$

Solving numerically (using for example Newton's method) we find $y= 0.05834= 5.834\, \%.%$

Comment: are you summing up just $(1+y)^{-k}$ for k from 1 to 4 or the entire equation $(1+y)^{-k} + 100(1+y)^{-4}$?

Comment: @Ayoshna: Just $(1+y)^{-k}$.  Those are the discount factors for the coupons. Clarified above.

Comment: Okay, I don't understand what's going on your summation. What happened to when k=2 and 3. How did you get $(1+y)^{-1}[1-(1+y)^{-4}]/ 1-(1+y)^{-4}$

Comment: Im summing a finite geometric series. Let $S = a + a^2 + a^3 + a^4$. Then $S - aS = a - a^5$ and $S = a(1-a^4)/(1-a)$

Comment: Okay, I'm trying to follow this and do it for a homework problem however I keep getting the incorrect value. Is there an easier way to do this or on the BA II plus calculator?

Comment: If you substitute $y = 0.05834$ into the formula you will get 114.49 -- did you check that?  This is the standard formula for yield to maturity and its a nonlinear equation with no closed form solution - so solving requires iteration -- or a calculator programmed for YTM.  I dont have a calculator.

Comment: Try bisection; guess $y0$ and $y1$ with $f(y0) < P$ and $f(y1) > P$ then set $y2 = (y0 + y1)/2$.  Repeat with $y2$ and whichever of $y1$ or $y0$ brackets the solution. Repeat a few times.